# Dont know how to fetch json data using jquery with handlebars

Tags: jquery, json, handlebars.js, each

Hi am new to `JSON` and all stuff people said about JavaScript templating engine for front end dynamic changes but but i cant able to proceed with this help me out

json file data.json

```
    {
    users: [{
        username: "alan",
        firstName: "Alan",
        lastName: "Johnson",
        email: "alan@test.com"
    }, {
        username: "allison",
        firstName: "Allison",
        lastName: "House",
        email: "allison@test.com"
    }, {
        username: "ryan",
        firstName: "Ryan",
        lastName: "Carson",
        email: "ryan@test.com"
    }]
}
```

by using get method in jquery i got the response of json file

```
 $(function() {
    var raw_template = $('#entry-template').html();
    var template = Handlebars.compile(raw_template);
    var placeHolder = $("#3cols");
    $.get("js/data.json", function(datas, status, xhr) {
        $.each(datas, function(key, val) {
            var html = template(val);
            placeHolder.append(html);
        });
    });
})
```

and my template is like

```
    <script id="entry-template" type="text/x-handlebars-template">          
     {{#each users}}
              <div class="col-md-4">
                <h2>{{username}}</h2>
                <p>{{firstName}}</p>
                <p><a href="">{{email}}</a>
                </p>
              </div>
        {{/each}}
    </script>
```

I want data to append in

```
 <div id="3cols" class="row"></div>
```

dont know what is happening nothing shows on screen but in console am getting response from json but no output

Answer (score 0):

With that JSON and that template, I would think the `#each` in the template would already iterate through your users so you don't need to separately do that with `.each()` in your Javascript.  I'd suggest changing your JS to this:

```
$(function() {
    var raw_template = $('#entry-template').html();
    var template = Handlebars.compile(raw_template);
    var placeHolder = $("#3cols");
    $.get("js/data.json", function(datas, status, xhr) {
        var html = template(datas);
        placeHolder.append(html);
    });
});
```

If that still doesn't work, then we will need to see exactly what `datas` is.  You can put a `console.log(datas)` right before doing `template(datas)` so we can see exactly what you're sending to the template.

Comment: Console log doesn't show anything.. :( `console.log("datas" +datas);`

Comment: @Woverine - What do you mean "doesn't show anything"?  Do you mean it doesn't get executed?  What's in `datas`?  Incidentally, doing `"datas"+datas` won't show you the contents you want to see.  That will probably just show you "Object object".  You need to do a plain `console.log(datas)` to see the actual contents of `datas`.

Comment: console shows only `GET http://localhost:8888/handlebars/js/data.json 200 OK 1ms jquery.js (line 9666)` nothing else